# Biblatex with apa style skips first entry in bibliography

Tags: apa-style

this is driving me nuts. When compiling my file I can only see the bibliography from the second entry on. The first one is skipped ?!?!?!?

Here's my def:

[image: This is the definition]

and in my output file I see this:

[image]

One is missing.

I referenced all of them in my chapter and they are printed fine in the text. Just the bibliography is wrong.

Any ideas ???

Comment: Make a small, complete example that we can compile and so test the issue. Show the blg-file.

Comment: is there a cache or something. I tried it in a new project and it worked fine. but in my other one its failing ??

Comment: I asked you to show the blg-File. Why don't you do it?

Comment: Have you run `bibtex`/`biber` again?

Comment: Any news here? Can you provide a proper [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)? What do the `.blg` and `.log` files for the problematic files say?